# JavaScript script to calculate network data consumption of a browser tab

Tags: javascript, networking, mobile-data

Is it possible to calculate or record the network data consumption of a browser tab using a JavaScript script or a chrome API?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Network Information API...
Please check MDN:

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API/)